# Azure IoT Edge - Inhibit Module to Module call to another device

Tags: azure-iot-edge

With the Azure IoT Edge SDK it is possible to invoke a method call from any device on any module running on any other device. [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.moduleclient.invokemethodasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-devices-client-moduleclient-invokemethodasync(system-string-microsoft-azure-devices-client-methodrequest))

This seems to be a big security risk:

1. Any malicious customer can simply hijack the edge device in front of him, and invoke methods  on modules on any other customer's device connected to the IoT hub
2. Any malicious edge module developer can release an edge module that does the same.

Ideally we would like to limit which module can call which other's method on the same device, but 100% we do not want one device to call methods on other devices.

Is this possible with Azure IoT edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting communication between modules/devices registered to an Azure IoT Edge is not available.

In regards to the security risk:

- Device and module need to be "part
  of" the same IoT Edge (Edge hub). See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.moduleclient.invokemethodasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-devices-client-moduleclient-invokemethodasync(system-string-microsoft-azure-devices-client-methodrequest)): *"Interactively
  invokes a method from an edge module to an edge device. **Both the
  edge module and the edge device need to be connected to the same edge
  hub**."* The deployment can only be done from the cloud (Azure IoT
  Hub or IoT Central).
- The deployer is in full control of what is
  deployed. Assuming you do not deploy modules nor edge connected
  devices that are unknown nor untested (security), it would not be
  possible to randomly hijack a device/module. Because of the
  deployment restriction the device and module are considered as being
  part of the same security zone. [More on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-security-architecture#security-in-iot).
- [More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-security-best-practices) on Azure IoT security best practices.

Limiting communication between modules/devices registered to an Azure IoT Edge could be a great option for other reasons. Please provide your feedback [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues).

Hope this help answer your question/concern.

Comment: Unfortunate.

We are not always 100% in control what else is running on the edge device, as legally is the customer's property. To make matters worse: more often than not the installation is executed on a VM by the customer's IT department in large installations. Hijacking an edge module's connection string and then maliciously calling random methods on your competitor's devices is trivial.

Even if we WERE in control of the hardware, with all the recent 0-day security exploits re: secure boot, user elevation, remote code execution, etc., it would be futile to think it is impossible at all

Comment: Deployment of an IoT Edge would require the same security measures as it would to deploy any other VM with applications if on a customers network.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/security?view=iotedge-2020-11.

Comment: I see Eric. My fault. Indeed, only modules that are connected via the same edgeHub (in a chained setup) can call each other. Modules only on the same IoT hub cannot. 

It is indeed a bit an issue that modules can call each other without having something like a "sender" info coming from the SDK, but that issue is minor. Sorry for the confusion